# $g(t) = \phi(f_1(t),\cdots,f_p(t))$ is differentiable and $g'(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{p} \phi(f_1(t),\cdots,f'_i(t),\cdots,f_p(t))$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $f_1,\cdots,f_p:I\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be differentiable paths and
>   $\phi:\mathbb{R}^m\times\cdots \times \mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be
>   a $p$-linear transformation. Show that the path $g:I\to\mathbb{R}^n$
>   given by $g(t) = \phi(f_1(t),\cdots,f_p(t))$ is differentiable and
>   $g'(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{p} \phi(f_1(t),\cdots,f'_i(t),\cdots,f_p(t))$

**First of all, how can $g$ be from $I\to\mathbb{R}^n$ if each coordinate is $f_i\in \mathbb{R}^m$? Shouldn't each function belong to \mathb{R}$**

This is crucial for me to understand why the derivative is given by that... And I'd appreciate if somebody show me how to get there because I truly didn't understand this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will show that the **linear map**  $D\phi: \mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^m \times\ldots \times \mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ at a point $(x_1, \ldots, x_p)$ is given by
\begin{align}
[D\phi(x_1, \ldots, x_p)](y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_p) = \sum^p_{j=1}\phi(x_1,x_2, \ldots, y_j, \ldots, x_p). 
\end{align}

Since $\phi$ is multilinear in $p$ slots, then we have that
\begin{align}
\phi(x_1+h_1, x_2+h_2, \ldots, x_p+h_p)-\phi(x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_p)= \phi(x_1, \ldots, x_p)+\sum_{j=1}^p \phi(x_1, \ldots, \hat x_j, \ldots, x_p)+\sum_{i<j}\phi(x_1, \ldots, \hat x_i, \ldots, \hat x_j, \ldots, x_p)+\ldots + \sum^p_{j=1}\phi(h_1, \ldots, \hat h_j, \ldots, h_p)-\phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)
\end{align}
where $\hat x_j$ indicate replacing the $x_j$ term with $h_j$ and likewise $\hat h_j$ means to replace $h_j$ with $x_j$. Hence we see that
\begin{align}
\phi(x_1+h_1, x_2+h_2, \ldots, x_p+h_p)-\phi(x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_p)-\sum_{j=1}^p \phi(x_1, \ldots, \hat x_j, \ldots, x_p)=\sum_{i<j}\phi(x_1, \ldots, \hat x_i, \ldots, \hat x_j, \ldots, x_p)+\ldots + \sum^p_{j=1}\phi(h_1, \ldots, \hat h_j, \ldots, h_p).
\end{align}
Using the definition that $\phi: U \rightarrow V$ is differentiable, if there exists a linear map $L$ such that
\begin{align}
\lim_{\|h\|_U\rightarrow 0} \frac{\|\phi(x+h)-\phi(x)-Lh\|_V}{\|h\|_U}=0
\end{align}
we see that
\begin{align}
Lh= \sum^p_{j=1}\phi(x_1, x_2, \ldots, \hat x_j, \ldots, x_p)
\end{align}
since the remainder terms goes to zeros at a rate that is faster than linear as $h\rightarrow 0$.

**Remark:** This is actually very simple but the language is very messy.

Any how, hence by the chain rule, you get what you want.